# Java EE HttpSession Page Switching

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm new in Java EE and I have a lot of questions...

Now I've this question:

Which way is better:

1. Create HashMap object as my HttpServlet class's variable and save information (parameters, attributes,..) in it and then take info from it (on submit HTML form);
2. Take information from HttpSession object from doPost(...) method (from request object).

Here's little sample:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>My HTML Project</TITLE>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <FORM ACTION="/My_Project/Main_Page" METHOD="post">
      <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="user" />
      <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="password" />
      <INPUT TYPE="submit" />
    </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

1.

```
@WebServlet("/Main_Page")
public class Main_Page extends HttpServlet
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    if(request.getSession(true).isNew())
    {
      myHashMap.put("user", "");
    }
    else
    {
      String userName = request.getParameter("user");
      if(userName != null) myHashMap.put("user", userName);
    }

/*...*/
    if(myHashMap.get("user") == null || myHashMap.get("user").equals("")) {/*do something...*/}
    else {myHashMap.setAttribute("loginDate", "16.04.2014 - 21:21:21"); /*...*/}
/*...*/
  }
}
```

2.

```
@WebServlet("/Main_Page")
public class Main_Page extends HttpServlet
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    HttpSession myHttpSession = request.getSession(true);

    String userName;

    if(myHttpSession.isNew())
    {
      userName = "";
    }
    else
    {
      userName = myHttpSession.getParameter("user");
    }

/*...*/
    if(userName == null || userName.equals("")) {/*do something...*/}
    else {G_session.setAttribute("loginDate", "16.04.2014 - 21:21:21"); /*...*/}
/*...*/
  }
}
```

Which way is better for **browser**'s manipulations (go back, go forward,..)?
Or, is there other better way than these?

*Sorry for my bad English...*

Comment: Please explain your exact problem. By the way, modern browsers let you open several views (including the same) of your web application in several tabs, so a navigation queue for all pages is not a good solution nor in session and **never** in a field in your servlet.

Comment: A Single Servlet instance may serve multiple http request. So keeping the local instance variable in Servlet is not advisable . if you want to keep the data for one request/response then keep it in request scope. if you want to keep it for entire session then keep it in session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse You should use `HttpSession` to store data! It is highly discouraged to use any mutable property in `HttpServlet`!

There is only one instance of your `HttpServlet` in your whole application life cycle to serve all of the request to this Servlet. So you should not use any property that can be mutated per HTTP request.

Moreover `HashMap` is not thread-safe in nature. So in multi-threaded environment you will observe inconsistent behavior from it. In worst case, `HashMap` in multi-threaded environment can cause for crashing your application. For details of HashMap race condition in multi-threaded environment see [this](http://mailinator.blogspot.hu/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html)!

Comment: While this sentence is true, it looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: So, I must create all variables in doPost method, not as class's variables. Right?